# How to use file response in Ajax query

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
//returning File Response in Controller action Method 
   
return File(MyMemoryStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "lp.xlsx");
```

I want to download this file but I have used ajax for passing data from view to Controller so it's returning to Ajax success function .

```
<script>
        $(".pfamlink").click(function()
        {
             $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                       url: "/Home/Excel",
                      data: { "data":$(this).html()},
                     
            success: function(response)
            {}
                   
        });
        });
        </script>
```

what I need to give in this function(response) to download returning file from controller?

or any suggestions for passing table data from view to controller without Ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

> what I need to give in this function(response) to download returning
> file from controller?

The FileContentResult is returned to the Ajax success function, the download was unsuccessful because we need to operate in success. Try to add an action to download, use `window.location` to redirect to the Download action in controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAsync()
        {
        ...
      //returning File Response in Controller action Method 
   
        return File(MyMemoryStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "lp.xlsx");
```

In your ajax success, change your code like below:

```
success: function (data) {
                window.location = '/yourcontrollername/Download';
            }
```